# Snappy Error: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

Please I am trying to use snappy for the first time to allow the user download PDF from my site. I previously used DomPDF but found it not suitable for the current situation. I first installed wkhtmltopdf, then I installed snappy using composer which installed it to c/users/computer-name/vendor (I am very new to composer). I copied the vendor folder to my project directory.

I added the code below;

```
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
    $snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
    echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');
```

as shown here: https://github.com/knplabs/snappy
The PDF downloads but does not open. Chrome says "Failed to load PDF document". When I open the PDF with notepad, I see the error;

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught RuntimeException: The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "The system cannot find the path specified.
"
stdout: ""
command: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality "https://www.google.com/&quot; "C:\Users\CHIDIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy5e42659b757116.59025588.pdf". in C:\xampp\htdocs\corporatecareer\templates\vendor\knplabs\knp-snappy\src\Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator.php:381

Please help. What are my missing. I know I am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` in snappy example is a linux binary location. Seems like you are using windows xampp. Download the wkhtmltopdf program from here https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and update you path where you extracted the binary like so.

```
$snappy = new Pdf('C:\path to where you extracted binary');
```

Also, make sure that the extracted path doesn't required admin privileges to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you said and used $snappy = new Pdf('C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf'); but now it shows an error "C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command". Please do you know what else I could do? Google is not showing any solution as yet.

Comment: Thanks it works now. Installed again and changed the extracted path.